# How can I integrate LDAP and AllAuth in a Django project?

Tags: django, ldap, django-allauth

I have recently inherited a Django project that uses AllAuth as its authentication system. The project needs to be changed to use LDAP for authentication and I would like to not have to tear out all of the AllAuth code. I know django-registration can use LDAP as a backend but AllAuth cannot. Is there any sort of patch around this?

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be (still) no direct LDAP integration provided by allauth ([no "ldap" is mentioned](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/search?q=ldap) in neither the source code nor the documentation). Hence,

1. LDAP needs to be integrated with another Python package ([python-ldap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ldap) or [django-auth-ldap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-auth-ldap)), first.
2. User creation in `allauth` then needs to be [customized via DefaultAccountAdapter](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#creating-and-populating-user-instances) (allauth docs) probably, depending on your needs and potential username conflicts. [GitHub issue 199](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/199) explains some of the problematics.

Note that this solution applies to the case of a combined use of allauth and LDAP. If you want to use LDAP exclusively for authentication then keeping allauth in the codebase probably makes little sense, or may just be an overhead; you'll have to tear it out.

Answer (score 1):

ldap configuration is fairly simple in django. I use the following settings for my application. I also use a python library called `python-ldap`

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
)

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://127.0.0.1:389"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=People,dc=local,dc=domain,dc=com",
                                   ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
}
```

Comment: i think the pip package name is `django-auth-ldap`

Comment: Does this answer the question? If [python-ldap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ldap) or [django-auth-ldap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-auth-ldap) integrate with an LDAP server how do you marry this with [django-allauth](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-allauth)? - Does the LDAP integration refer to `django.contrib.auth` `User` instances allauth is also referring to? What about user creation, authentication and permissions?